# Temperature controller that can be accessed by a mobile?

Tags: fermentation-temperature, temperature-control

I ferment my beer in a fridge located in my summer house. I've been using STC-1000 but one of it's drawbacks is that there is no logging of temperature. Is there any better thermostat that can control heating, cooling, has predefined programs and additionaly can be accessed trough a web panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the closest thing you can get with out spending an arm and a leg is getting a [brewPI](http://www.brewpi.com/blog/), I dont have one, but it says it can log locally and has a bunch of different functions, and a web interface. you may be able to follow this [guide](http://www.brewpi.com/fridge-hacking-guide/) to hack your existing fridge to be compatible.

personally, i like to build things so i would get a raspberry Pi, put a Lamp server on it, and make my own controller.